# Ansible copy module does not support backup of directory and permissions of directory

Tags: linux, ansible

In the official documentation also its mentioned that copy works on files. 
I am able to copy a directory but can not take the backup of existing directory.

What could be the best way to do it without shell/command module ? Something directly ansible or am i missing something with copy module ?

Also same permissions `0777` set for file work but not for directory.

Comment: have you looked at the synchronize module? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html

Comment: This module does not have options for backup or permissions.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by an option for backup? For most purposes this could just be anything that copies the files off. To my knowledge "an option for backup" is not a specific thing.

Comment: Also, read up on asynchronous, because by default, it keeps permissions. By using the archive flag it ignores them. This Ansible module has archive set by default, but can be changed.

Comment: Actually my purpose is to take backup of existing directory(this directory is a part of java app) so that if new changed direstory breaks the app i could revert. If il sync wont have any option to revert the change

Comment: But yes sync solves the permission problem but does not work for my usecase.

Comment: Stupid autocorrect. That was supposed to be archive, not asynchronous

Comment: You missed the delete option. Just created an answer including it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the synchronize module for your backups and restores.

```
- name: back up remote dir to local
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - synchronize:
      src: /dir/for/backup
      dest: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}":/dir/to/store/backup
      recursive: yes
      perms: yes
    delegate_to: <remote_host>

- name: restore local dir to remote
  hosts: <remote_hosts>
  tasks:
  - synchronize:
      src: /path/to/backup/dir
      dest: /path/to/dest/dir
      recursive: yes
      perms: yes
      delete: yes
```